# Transformations for Logistic Regression Predictors

Tags: regression, logistic, data-transformation, predictor

I was curious about what types of transformations (if any) are used on predictors for logistic regression.

Linear regression transformations seem fairly straightforward; scatter and density plots can help identify if logging the predictors or using a polynomial is necessary. I haven't read too much on similar types of predictor transformations for logistic models. I was just curious if there are common transformations and, if so, how are they identified (graph, etc.)?

Comment: Normality assumptions for logistic regression models aren't the same as in for linear regression models; homogeneity in the residuals' variance assumption doesn't apply in logistic regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more challenging to detect non-linear effects in logistic regression as opposed to linear regression, but some possible answers are to plot the predictors vs the deviance residuals or pearson residuals.

Or, look at sample proportions in categories defined by the predicted values (analogous to the hosmer lemeshow chi square). If there is major lack of fit there, that could indicate non-linear predictor effects. Then, try polynomial terms (or general non-linear regression approaches) and see if that improves the agreement between predicted and observed proportions.

Comment: Try with splines!

Comment: thats what i meant by non-linear regression approaches.

Comment: Then maybe you could extend your answer to include this details!

Comment: It already contains that detail!! Maybe you should post a better answer if you prefer!!!